# Springboot Webflux accesslog: What are the two numbers at the end please?

Tags: spring-webflux, access-log

Small question regarding how to interpret a SpringBoot Webflux app access log please.

Currently, in my logs, more precisely access logs, I can see:

```
2021-07-31 13:46:19.913  INFO [service,,] 10 --- [or-http-epoll-1] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : ip - - [31/Jul/2021:13:46:19 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 3349 6

2021-07-31 13:47:18.531  INFO [service,,] 10 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : ip - - [31/Jul/2021:13:47:18 +0000] "GET /health/liveness HTTP/2.0" 200 3312 8

2021-07-31 13:47:33.347  INFO [service,,] 10 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : ip - - [31/Jul/2021:13:47:33 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 3349 11
```

I understand the 200 is probably my http response, I return http 200.

But I am having a hard time understanding what are the last two numbers please.

**3349 6**

**3312 8**

**3349 11**

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on log format definition, but it looks like the larger number is response size in bytes and the smaller is processing time of the request in ms.

I'll look at documentation to see where I'd expect to find the log format definition for a spring webflux app. I'd expect the format to be defined in a similar way to httpd access logs ( documentation for those is at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html)

Comment: It always seems that Baeldung results come higher than actual Spring documentation! Here's a good pointer though - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-tomcat-logs

Comment: Oh sorry, you are using Netty - it will be similar to tomcat though

Comment: Yes, Webflux, hence Netty. But I took your advice, and stared at the logs for a good 5 minutes straight. It seems that indeed, one is the size in byte, one is the time taken. Unfortunately, I also have actuator/micrometer, and the metric reported time is slightly higher, while the byte size is slightly lower, but both very close